# Can esper/siddhi generate new stream according to the group by?

Tags: stream, wso2, esper, siddhi, wso2-cep

I want to devide each group into a new stream(I want the operation for the group, not for the stream) .Dose there any methods to do that in esper or siddhi?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this can be solved by Esper
[multiple insert clauses](http://espertech.com/esper/release-5.5.0/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#split_overview)

Comment: this can be done by context,but another problem occured:if i want to correlate two different event streams,for example: 
schema EventA (a string, b string)
schema EventB (c string, d string)
and i want group EventA by a,b and group EventB by d, and the correlation condition is EventA.b = EventB.d
This can not be done by context,though esper has multiple context,but it seems not work